# Fitting $Gal(K'/F')$ into $Gal(K/F)$ if $F'/F$ and $K'$ is a splitting field over $F'$, and $K$ splitting over $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

Suppose $F'/F$ is a field extension, and suppose $f \in F[x]$ is a polynomial. Then $f \in F'[x]$ as well obviously.

So let $K'$ be a splitting field for $f$ over $F'$ and $K$ a splitting field for $f$ over $F$.

Then how do we embed $Gal(K'/F')$ into $Gal(K/F)$?

I feel $K' = F'[\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_m]$ and $K = F[\beta_1, ..., \beta_n]$ and $m \leq n$. Then $Gal(K'/F')$ is 'smaller' than $Gal(K/F)$ cos I imagine we have up to homomorphism that some of the $\beta_i$ are in $F'$, and the remaining $\beta_i$ are $\alpha_i$.

So I tried to draw a comparison between the roots $\alpha_i$ and the roots $\beta_i$ but it didn't really go anywhere. I'm now thinking that may not be the right approach.

How does one go about constructing this embedding?

Comment: I think you ought to assume that $f$ has no repeated roots in any extension, and deal with that case. Then surely $m=n$ at least. Since all splitting fields of $f$ over $F$ are isomorphic we can choose to work with any one of them. So wlog we can assume that we are working in the algebraic closure of $F'[\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n]$: and so the $\alpha_i$ are precisely the $\beta_i$.

Comment: To reformulate slightly  the argument of @ancientmathematician, suppose $\gamma_{1}, \dots, \gamma_{n}$ are the roots of $f$ in $K´$, Then you can take $K$ to be $F[\gamma_{1}, \dots, \gamma_{n}]$, and the embedding is just the restriction to $K$..